# Intel core i3 2350m - can a laptop be without an integrated gpu?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, cpu, integrated-graphics

first of all, thanks for trying to help!
I have a strange problem with my laptop (SONY VAIO VPCEH35en).

*Been 5 years since I purchased it, and honestly Iam finding it difficult to spend my parents' money for buying a new laptop.. So I was hoping to know if there's any solution before spending.*

http://www.sony.co.in/electronics/support/laptop-pc-vpc-series/vpceh35en/specifications

specs:
   Intel i3 2350m, Nvidia 410m 512mb, 8gb ddr3 ram, 320gb hdd.

It started a few months back - I generally used to overclock my GPU for some gaming and that seemed to have some effect on it- video stuttering that graduateed into windows crashing (I understand the long term effects of overclocking)

One day the it failed to start with any video output, just showed a blank screen.
gave it for repair, they said the **GPU had short circuited**. Then they removed the gpu from the circuit and, according to basic knowledge, it should fall back to the integrated gpu, that should be intel HD 3000.

Exactly that doesn't happen! Windows boots as if there's no gpu (with unchangeable full brightness, no video playback support).
Before, when everything was fine, I tried to find if there is an integrated intell gpu but it wasnt found even in bios.

Installing the specified graphics drivers from intel make the blank black screen problem come again, making the pc unusable.

Currently I'm running ubuntu 17.04 (a slightly long story- I got it to work with the generic drivers ), in short, system info shows Graphics :Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 4.0, 256 bits).

The basic problem for me is that I cannot get windows to run properly (in a usable state) on it **because of absence of any gpu** it seems.

*Please tell me is it possible that a 2nd gen i3 2350m is without the integrated graphics? 
Is there any way that repair people can enable the gpu (doesnt show up in bios) if it's there?*

Comment: The firmware may not be designed to fall back on the integrated GPU, in which case you're SOL.

Comment: Wait a sec, you can get into and **see** the BIOS menus? That is only possible if a GPU is working!

Comment: Your processor has an iGPU.  It’s practically worthless due to the generation of processor you have but it exists

Comment: Why would a repair place remove the video card and give the laptop back to you non-functional? You can replace the video card or request that they make the laptop work properly. I’d get a second opinion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all inputs, they were very helpful! Really appreciate it.